# Python list() vs list comprehension building speed

Tags: python, performance, list, list-comprehension, python-2.x

This is interesting; `list()` to force an iterator to get the actual list is so much faster than `[x for x in someList]` (comprehension).

Is this for real or is my test just too simple?
Below is the code:

```
import time    

timer = time.clock()
for i in xrange(90):

    #localList = [x for x in xrange(1000000)]   #Very slow, took me 6.8s
    localList = list(xrange(1000000))           #Very fast, took me 0.9s

    print localList[999999] #make sure list is really evaluated.

print "Total time: ", time.clock() - timer
```

Comment: Python 3.4 gives 5.5s vs 3.6s with `timeit`, for a 10^6 list.

Comment: @user5061: the timings here would be a lot better if wrapped in a function and locals are used. In Python 3, a list comprehension gets its own scope (like a generator expression) and locals are faster.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The list comprehension executes the loop in Python bytecode, just like a regular `for` loop.

The `list()` call iterates entirely in C code, which is far faster.

The bytecode for the list comprehension looks like this:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile("[x for x in xrange(1000000)]", '<stdin>', 'exec'))
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (xrange)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (1000000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (x)
             19 LOAD_NAME                1 (x)
             22 LIST_APPEND              2
             25 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   28 POP_TOP             
             29 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `>>` pointers roughly give you the boundaries of the loop being executed, so you have 1 million `STORE_NAME`, `LOAD_NAME` and `LIST_APPEND` steps to execute in the Python bytecode evaluation loop.

`list()` on the other hand just grabs the values from the `xrange()` iterable directly by using the C API for object iteration, and it can use the length of the `xrange()` object to pre-allocate the list object rather than grow it dynamically.

Comment: Is that just an implementation detail? Could the compiler automatically transform the list comprehension anytime it sees it in that form?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: transform it into what exactly?

Comment: to the fast version: to a `list(iterable)` form (of course using the builtin `list`, in case it was locally defined). from the `[v for v in iterable]` form.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: It may be able to; I cannot at the moment think of a reason why the form couldn't be replaced by `list()`. I do see the mistake often enough (`rows = [row for row in csvreader]`, or `lines = [line for line in fileobj]`, etc.). I'll see about posting that to the python-ideas list.

Comment: I believe the same happens with dict() vs {d:True for d in someList} for example?
What would the best way to init a dict of that kind?

Comment: @user1777914: `dict.fromkeys(someList, True)`.

Answer (score -2):

This no longer seems to hold true (I checked Python 3.7-3.10).
The list comprehension is faster than the list function.
I've heard rumors of speedups coming in 3.10 and 3.11 as well.

Comment: can you please publish some numbers? `%timeit l=[x for x in range(1000000)] => 
22.8 ms ± 207 µs per loop` vs `%timeit l=list(range(1000000)) => 12.1 ms ± 176 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` (python 3.9.12)