# random.shuffle(range(10)) report TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to generate a random list,

```
In [20]: num_arr = list(range(10))
In [22]: random.shuffle(num_arr)
In [23]: print(num_arr)
[8, 0, 7, 3, 9, 4, 1, 2, 6, 5]
```

However, I tried

```
In [24]: num_arr = range(10)
In [25]: random.shuffle(num_arr)
TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment
```

I intend to learn the mechanism behind why it's not working?
Could you please provide any hints?

Comment: It looks like the shuffle function uses item assignment like `obj[0]` to move items about in-place.

Comment: You can do what you want if you use `random.sample()`.

Comment: welcome to the python 3... `shuffle(range())` works fine in python 2.7 =)

Comment: Are you using Python 3? I tried this on Python 2.7 and had no problem. `range()` in Python 2.7 returns a `list`, but I know Python 3 changed `range()` to be the same as `xrange()` in Python 2, so there might lie the difference.

Comment: @berkelem: Yes, it would work fine in Python 2.x (because `range` is implemented inefficiently to make new `list`s when 99% of the time you don't need one).

Comment: @lenik: `shuffle(range())` is pretty pointless though, if you actually construct the new `range` in the call. `random.sample(range(n), n)` would be useful at least (since it constructs and returns a brand new `list`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger you know what I meant, so, sorry, I'm not going to explain it =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.shuffle` shuffles the given sequence, **in-place**, so it cannot be an immutable `iterable`, such as `range`. You need to provide a `list`.

The recommended way to fix your code is to create a `list` out of your `range`, by passing it to the `list` type constructor, i.e. `list(range(10))`.

```
num_arr = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(num_arr)
```

Another (and not so common) way to do it would be to use list comprehension:

```
num_arr = [n for n in range(10)]
random.shuffle(num_arr)
```

However, note that [using list constructor could be much faster than using list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356846/python-list-vs-list-comprehension-building-speed)

Comment: Please don't suggest using the no-op `list` comprehension when plain `list(range(10))` works (especially in a large block that makes it seem like "the answer"). It just perpetuates a common beginner mistake of using `list` comprehensions unnecessarily; `list(range(10))` is *the* correct way to convert.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Fair comment. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`random.shuffle` requires a list of numbers to shuffle, which `range(10)` doesn't provide. Look at what `range(10)` returns:

```
num_arr = range(10)
num_arr
range(0, 10)

type(num_arr)
<class 'range'>
```

`range()` doesn't return a list of numbers, it returns an object of type `range`. `range` objects are lazy iterables (not `iterators`)  that don't generate their output when they're created. You need to access the values in a `range` object, either by looping over it with a for loop, or converting it to a list all at once with `list`

```
list(num_arr)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `shuffle` function requires a list to passed, and the range function works more like a generator. To see this in action we'll make our own `my_range` function to replicate the range function and try to pass it to shuffle, and you'll get a similar error.

```
import random

def my_range(num: int):
    begin = 0
    while begin < num:
        yield begin
        begin += 1

f = random.shuffle(my_range(10))
```